# React front-end + Express.js Sessions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, session, cookies

I have backend API based on Express.js and clientside based on React-Redux.

Authentification to my API is done by Express.js sessions. User log-in by Passport (OAuth2) and after that user's cookie is saved to database connected with his user-id. This cookie is also in client browsers's cookie storage.

If you send next request to this API, server checks your cookie with database and if its correct it answer you data.

It was working well when I was not using React, but now clientside must somehow know that user is logged even before u make some request (when React app is loaded).

Session cookie is saved even when user is not logged, so I am lost.

How to do it?

**Image about how it works:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g0ei.png

**ADDITIONAL RESEARCH:**

I was investigating https://www.instagram.com/ for example... They using session cookie... If I delete this cookie, user is logouted, also when I use this cookie in Postman, I can fetch API. But I can't find any request what checking if user is logged. React App just know it right after initial data from server are recieved. Maybe they pushing this information into React from server? Not by calling APi after loading app?

Comment: Noone from 22 people know?

Comment: From a design perspective, you can't rely on the client side to "know" anything. The client side is the wild jungle of the internet. They will send you cookies. They will not send you cookies. They will send you incorrect cookies. The only control you have is on the server side. That means that every request--for React web content, for data, for anything--must be screened on the server side for authentication.

Comment: So when you say, "clientside must somehow know that user is logged even before u make some request"--nope, that's not how it works. The client side will make requests anyway. All sorts of requests. Your server's job is to answer the way you want.

Comment: @AndyTaton But I just need when I load React app from server for first time (I launch browser) to be able to tell to inital React's state that user is logged to show UI for logged user and not for unlogged....

Comment: @AndyTaton I know that client is dumb, I know that I need handle every request, but I dont know how to tell React when is user logged after loading app

Comment: What I usually do is, on the client-side page, create a `componentDidMount()` method that sends a simple request to an `/isloggedin` API on the server. The server uses the client session/cookie/JWT/whatever to tell the client whether they are logged in or not, maybe along with some user info (their name, avatar image location, etc.). The client `state` and display are modified accordingly.

Comment: @AndyTaton I was investigating https://www.instagram.com/ for example... They using session cookie... If I delete this cookie, user is logouted, also when I use this cookie in Postman, I can fetch API. But I can't find any request what checking if user is logged. React App just know it right after initial data from server are recieved. Maybe they pushing this information into React from server? Not by calling APi after loading app?

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was the same as Andy Taton expressed in his answer. It goes somehow like this:

Client side:

```
componentDidMount() {
    api('/profile').get().then(data => {
        console.log('/profile data', data)
    })
}
```

Server side:

```
  app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    if (req.user) {
      db.Favorite.find({ uid: req.user._id }).then(user => {
        return res.status(200).json(user)
      })
    } else {
      return res.status(403).json({ message: 'you are not logged in' })
    }
  })
```

Your request must contain **credentials: "include"** if using ES6 fetch, or **withCredentials: true** if using axios.

Check [this code sample](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-set-up-twitter-oauth-using-passport-js-and-reactjs-9ffa6f49ef0/), it contains a working example with Twitter authentication.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that worked for me to solve this.

Since the frontend doesn't know the user, but the backend can tell who the user is by the presence of the cookie and the passport created property request.user, we have to ASK THE BACKEND who the user is.

Create a route in the backend, like api/user. It just looks for the cookie and gets the user and sends that json back. If there is no user, the server replies back that there is no user. Maybe we could redirect to passport login right here instead, but I just did the window.open(/auth/github) in the frontend here.

TLDR, the Frontend doesn't know the user? Ask the backend.